# How to move pieces in chess?

Tags: java, chess

I am currently working on designing abstract classes for a possible chess game.
I needed help regarding how to move different pieces(for example queen, knight)

```
public class MyPiece extends Piece {

@Override
public boolean canMove(int x, int y) {
    return (this.x != x && Math.abs(this.y - y) == 1);
}
}
```

The above code displays a sample for some piece that can just move up and down. It is not a valid chess move. So if i were to move a queen how would i go about?To simply things we are just assuming that we already have a board of matrix (x,y) 8 by 8.

Comment: Your sample doesn't do what you say ("just move up and down"); I think you mean `this.x == x`

Comment: That depends on many factors. Where you are standing. If another figure is in your way, ...

Comment: Yea i forgot to mention that , this is assuming nothing is in the way. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially for chess queen it is not so simple. You have to:

1. determine that the move straight, i.e. horizontal, vertical, or diagonal.
2. That there are no other pieces on the way.

So,

- To determine that move is horizontal check `this.x == x && this.y != y`
- To determine that move is vertical check `this.y == y && this.x != x`
- To determine diagonal check `Math.abs(this.x - x) == Math.abs(this.y - y)`

Now chose the direction, iterate over the way and check that your `matrix` does not contain elements in cells that are going to be passed by queen during this move.

Comment: Right i forgot to mention that we are just assuming nothing is in the way for simplicity. The canmove method is only called if we "can move"  Thanks a lot ! That helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think in terms of "Given piece P on location (x,y) on the board which coordinates can the piece move to?".  I.e. for a rook on (1,1) you can move to (1,2)..(1,8) and (2,1)..(8,1).

Unfortunately there are additional restrictions, for example:

- Most pieces cannot pass other pieces. Hence, you need to know the coordinates of pieces on the board.
- Kings cannot move into a check. Hence, you need to know the locations of where the opponents pieces can move to.
- Kings can castle if they have not moved (it is not enough to be in the original position).  Hence you need to know the history of the game.

Modelling a chess game is an interesting exercise, but perhaps you should try checkers first to get accustomed to working with an abstract representation of a physical game, and then have a second go at chess?

Comment: Thats a very good point you made i almost forgot. Kings can not move when they are checked ! so i would needed to have a boolean method to see if "ischecked" is true or not. Thanks a bunch. i cant add reps unfortunately because i am a new user and i am restricted.

Comment: @user1772052: Kings cannot castle whilst in check, either.  I've forgotten, but it may also be true that kings can not castle through check, either.

Comment: Kings can move when in check (otherwise the game would be over at the first check). You cannot move _into_ a check.

Answer (score 1):

Quick though:

Introduce an interface called "Moveable". Your figure classes (you call them "pieces") will be defined like this. Extract your canMove() method into this interface and add move() method returning some unchecked exception if it fails.

```
 public class MyPiece extends Piece implements Moveable{
//your code goes here
 }
```

Create enum called MovementPossibilities. Here you should store all possible movements. Each movement possibility consists of possible directions (binary status, just on/off, true/false, can move in that direction/cannot). For every direction, introduce three integers -> minStep, maxStep, stride. Obviously, they tell you how much your figure can move in given direction.

This attemp is good in one thing - it first lets you test if your figure can move in that direction. If no, no other tests are needed.